# What could/should I do to care about security in my case?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, security, internationalization

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.1.0 and I would like to focus on security on using the [I18n gem](https://github.com/svenfuchs/i18n) for internationalization purposes.

At this time I have:

```
# in .yml file
key_1_html: "%{var_1} is just a test"

# in view, controller and model files
I18n.t('key_1_html', :var_1 => 'Test variable')
```

The `Test variable` is/represent an input from users so I should consider that as a potential hacking.

**What could/should I do to care about security in my case?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under normal Rails (3.x) usage, you don't have to do anything.

Even if some HTML code or javascript gets into the string returned from i18n, if you are outputting strings returned from i18n in ordinary ways, any HTML in them (whether from the template or the variable) will be escaped and show up as literal source in the webpage.

You'd have to manually mark a string returned by i18n as .html_safe to get it to be delivered as html source.

So don't do that.

Try it yourself, and see.

```
I18n.t('key_1_html', :var_1 => '/<script>danger!</script>')
```

Now output that in an ERB template, see what happens.

If you're doing something odd with i18n other than outputting it through typical Rails templates to the browser, then you'll need to say what, and what your concern is.

I think maybe this guide is what you're looking for, for an overview of Rails security issues:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html

See Section 8 on "Injection".

Comment: BTW: Under what circumstances Ruby on Rails 3.x doesn't handle escaping? Are there some? If so, what/when?

Comment: Well, Rails 3.x DOES handle escaping for anything in an .erb template, output with <%= %>, unless the string has been marked with .htmlsafe. Rails will also handle protecting against SQL injection if you are using ActiveRecord properly. However, there are a potentially infinite number of cases where rails does not handle escaping, since there are an infinite number of things you can do with rails, you can do whatever the heck you want with it, including things that don't make any sense or nobody's done before.  Some of those circumstances, Rails won't handle escaping.

Comment: Can you give me two examples of **extreme cases** in which Ruby on Rails *handles* and *do not handle* escaping?

Comment: Is this for an exam or something?